# Adminhtml 'Add New' Action with Subtypes

Tags: adminhtml, forms, adminform

I'm trying to replicate the way the 'add new' button works in the product section of the admin. I have a custom model that I've set up, have displaying on a grid, have an 'add new' button, and have that linked up to a form. What I'd like to do is replicate the way the add new product functionality works, specifically allowing for the user to choose a type from a dropdown on a new page, and then showing the next step of the form (depending on the type chosen).

I see the way this is being done for products in the core code, but it seems like a sloppy mess of inline JS, written just for that purpose.

Here's the form the product page uses:

```
<?php    
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Settings extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->setChild('continue_button',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                ->setData(array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Continue'),
                    'onclick'   => "setSettings('".$this->getContinueUrl()."','attribute_set_id','product_type')",
                    'class'     => 'save'
                    ))
                );
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('settings', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Create Product Settings')));

        $entityType = Mage::registry('product')->getResource()->getEntityType();

        $fieldset->addField('attribute_set_id', 'select', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attribute Set'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attribute Set'),
            'name'  => 'set',
            'value' => $entityType->getDefaultAttributeSetId(),
            'values'=> Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
                ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType->getId())
                ->load()
                ->toOptionArray()
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('product_type', 'select', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Type'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Type'),
            'name'  => 'type',
            'value' => '',
            'values'=> Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type')->getOptionArray()
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('continue_button', 'note', array(
            'text' => $this->getChildHtml('continue_button'),
        ));

        $this->setForm($form);
    }

    public function getContinueUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/new', array(
            '_current'  => true,
            'set'       => '{{attribute_set}}',
            'type'      => '{{type}}'
        ));
    }
}
```

As you can see, the onClick => 'setSettings' part is the action for the 'continue' button. This is the part that I've gotten up to in my own form, but I do not want to rewrite the setSettings function in another phtml file the way it is done in core. Is there no neater way to get a multi-step adminhtml forms working?

Thank you for your help!